# PHP SQL - login with multiple user's roles

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, session, prepared-statement

I have an issue with my login form. 
Basically, I want to be redirected to a different PHP page depends on the user role.

```
<?php
session_start(); 
$error = ''; 
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
$error = "Username or Password is invalid";
}
else{
// Define $username and $password
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

// mysqli_connect() function opens a new connection to the MySQL server.
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "gbadacdb");
// SQL query to fetch information of registerd users and finds user match.
$query = "SELECT * FROM users where username=? AND password=? LIMIT 1";
// To protect MySQL injection for Security purpose
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $username, $password, $id_role);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($username, $password,$id_role);
$stmt->store_result();
if($stmt->fetch()) //fetching the contents of the row {
$_SESSION['login_user'] = $username; // Initializing Session
if ($_SESSION['id_role'] == 1){
header("location: user.php"); // Redirecting To Profile Page
}
else
{
    header("location: admin.php");
}
}
mysqli_close($conn); // Closing Connection
}
?>
```

I have tried with `if()` and `switch()`, but nothing works.

There are no error messages when I press "submit" on login form, nothing happens.
Without this, `if ($_SESSION['id_role'] == 1)` everything works fine, except that I'm redirected to the same page, it doesn't matter if the user is admin or not.

Comment: `$_SESSION['id_role']` isn't set to anything - perhaps you meant to store `$id_role` from your query in it?

Comment: Please don't store plaintext passwords!

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use ***PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)*** to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).  ***It is not necessary to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: I will change the encryption of the passwords to md5. So, how can I change this code to be redirected to a different PHP page depends on the user role?

Comment: `$stmt->bind_param("ss", $username, $password, $id_role);` < that line is failing. 2 binds, 3 variables.

Comment: ok, I have deleted $id_role, I can log in now, but I'm not redirected to the correct PHP file depends on id_role. Can you help me with that?